# Pass content from TypoScript to fluid template in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.x, typo3-7.6.x

I would like to read content via TypoScript and render it through a custom Fluid template. Without css_styled_content or fluid_styled_content.

```
temp.test = CONTENT
temp.test {
  table = tt_content
  select.languageField = 1
  select.selectFields = bodytext,image,header,header_link
  select.where = colPos = 1
  renderObj = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  renderObj {
    file = path/to/Teaser.html
  }
}
```

This works with strings, say

```
<f:debug>{data.header}</f:debug>
```

But not with

```
<f:debug>{data.image}</f:debug>
```

returning only the number of images.

Now, in a classic TypoScript RenderObj (maybe a COA), you would have added something like

```
10 = FILES
10 {
  required = 1
  references {
    table = tt_content
    fieldName = image
  }
  renderObj = IMAGE
  renderObj {
    file.import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
    file.width=654
    file.height = 327c
    //stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
    altText.data = file:current:description // file:current:title // file:current:alternative
  }
}
```

While nowadays, we want to do that in the Fluid template. But how to resolve the FAL image to pass it to the fluid template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor` data processor that will fetch the file data for you so you can access it with `{files}` in your template.

```
renderObj = FLUIDTEMPLATE
renderObj {
  file = path/to/Teaser.html
  dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    10.references.fieldName = image
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, here! https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is all image information are stored in a different table called "sys_file_reference". Selecting "tt_content.image" will not help you here. There are 2 ways to solve this problem, IMHO.

1) Create your own viewhelper. This VH can be utilized to query the images as it is done [here](http://www.nicolas-stey.de/typo3-cms/eintrag/zugriff-in-extbase-auf-filereferences-fal.html).

2) Create a small TypoScript lib and use it as f:cObject in your fluid template. This is described [here](http://www.typo3-probleme.de/2015/09/18/typo3-gridelements-tt_content-felder-auslesen-inkl-image/).

I'm not saying that my solution is the best one. But it's the only one I'm aware of. Looking forward seeing better solutions ;)

Comment: Thanks – I think there is one, by Daniel!

Comment: Thx for your answer. I also prefer Daniel's solution!